# keyboard layout is disabled in kde

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout, kubuntu, kde-neon

I have kde Neon

```
 ~ ? screenfetch 
              `..---+/---..`                saeb@saeb-fujitsu
          `---.``   ``   `.---.`            OS: KDE neon 5.17
       .--.`        ``        `-:-.         Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.0.0-37-generic
     `:/:     `.----//----.`     :/-        Uptime: 20h 30m
    .:.    `---`          `--.`    .:`      Packages: 2396
   .:`   `--`                .:-    `:.     Shell: fish 2.7.1
  `/    `:.      `.-::-.`      -:`   `/`    Resolution: 1366x768
  /.    /.     `:++++++++:`     .:    .:    DE: KDE 5.64.0 / Plasma 5.17.4
 `/    .:     `+++++++++++/      /`   `+`   WM: KWin
 /+`   --     .++++++++++++`     :.   .+:   GTK Theme: Breeze [GTK3]
 `/    .:     `+++++++++++/      /`   `+`   CPU: Intel Core i7-3632QM @ 8x 3.2GHz [65.0°C]
  /`    /.     `:++++++++:`     .:    .:    GPU: GeForce GT 620M
  ./    `:.      `.:::-.`      -:`   `/`    RAM: 1726MiB / 7833MiB
   .:`   `--`                .:-    `:.    
    .:.    `---`          `--.`    .:`     
     `:/:     `.----//----.`     :/-       
       .-:.`        ``        `-:-.        
          `---.``   ``   `.---.`           
              `..---+/---..`               
 ~ ?
```

I want set caps lock as my keyboard layout switcher But I cant its settings are disabled
how I can enable that?

[image: my keyboard setting]

[image: my keyboard setting]

[image: my keyboard setting]

Answer (score 1):

It is some kind of a glitch with the latest Plasma. As you can see on the screenshots above, Plasma can't detect the keyboard model. Connect an external keyboard to your system (or just a different keyboard model), change your settings and off you go :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem is caused missing regional settings.

Check:

**System Settings/Regional Settings** -> **Language**.

You can add languages by clicking on the "Add languages" button.

Answer (score 0):

Running `kcmshell5 kcm_keyboard` might help.

In my case, it showed that parsing the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` file failed due to syntax problem in the XML structure. After fixing that, my keyboard layout tab works now.